# Objective C: Resizing a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to resize my UIImageView.  What I tried was to directly edit the frame of the image view like so

```
    verticalBar.frame = CGRectMake(verticalBar.frame.origin.x, verticalBar.frame.origin.y, verticalBar.frame.size.width, verticalBar.frame.size.height);
```

Yet even when I simply didn't change any of the values the Image contorted greatly.  What I mean by this is I had a rotated rectangle(I used CGAfflineTransformMakeRotation) at a 45 degree angle but when I tried editing its frame as shown above the rectangle became 5 times as wide.  Not sure what the problem is.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `UIView frame`:

> However, if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

So either leave the transform in place  and update the image view's `center` and `bounds`, or reset the transform to set the `frame`.

Comment: I tried editing the bounds verticalBar.bounds = CGRectMake(...  But it still gave the same contorted results.  Is there a different way to edit bounds.